# Error when use nth-child to create 2 columns

Tags: css

I have a list items

```
<ul id="two-colums">
   <li>01 Clean filter</li>
   <li>02 Change filter</li>
   <li>03 Change blower</li>
   <li>04 Wash blower</li>
   <li>05 Change fan belting</li>
   ...
   <li>32 Check & comb dented coil fin</li>
   <li>33 Check CHW pipe leakage with visual test</li>
</ul>
```

And my custom css

```
#two-columns li {
   width: 50%;
}
#two-columns li:nth-child(n+13) {
   float: right;
}
```

This is my error
[image: error 2 columns]

Comment: If you want only two columns shouldn't you start the second column off with 17 or 18? 33 items/2 colunms = 17 items and 16 items.

Comment: What is the *error*? Is it that the split is uneven (if yes, that's because of your selector) or is it that the second column is not top aligned or ...?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `n` in the id.

Change the html:

`id="two-colums"` into `id="two-columns`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a better way to make 2 columns:

```css
.flexMain {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
ul {
  max-width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<main class="flexMain">
  <ul id="column1">
    <li>01 Clean filter</li>
    <li>02 Change filter</li>
    <li>03 Change blower</li>
    <li>04 Wash blower</li>
    <li>05 Change fan belting</li>
    <li>06</li>
    <li>07</li>
    <li>08</li>
    <li>09</li>
    <li>10</li>
    <li>11</li>
    <li>12</li>
    <li>13</li>
    <li>14</li>
    <li>15</li>
    <li>16</li>
    <li>17</li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="column2">
    <li>18</li>
    <li>19</li>
    <li>20</li>
    <li>21</li>
    <li>22</li>
    <li>23</li>
    <li>24</li>
    <li>25</li>
    <li>26</li>
    <li>27</li>
    <li>28</li>
    <li>29</li>
    <li>30</li>
    <li>31</li>
    <li>32 Check &amp; comb dented coil fin</li>
    <li>33 Check CHW pipe leakage with visual test</li>
  </ul>
</main>
```

Use [flexbox](https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-visual-guide-to-css3-flexbox-properties). I made 2 `ul`s to make it easier.

Comment: Making 2 `<ul>` is outside of the scope of this question

Answer (score 0):

You can also use CSS columns

```
#two-columns {
  -webkit-columns: 2;
  -moz-columns: 2;
  columns: 2;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eprQMb